# Adding something to a dynamic array

Tags: c++

I want to add X to the end of my Array if the array is full I double the size but i'm having trouble inserting it into newArray after I get it into newArray I use pointers to switch dynamicArray to newArray.

```
  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class IntegerDynamicArray {
    public:
        IntegerDynamicArray();    
      ~IntegerDynamicArray();
        int add(int x);
    private:
        int * dynamicArray;
        int currentSize=maxSize;
        int maxSize=4;

};``

IntegerDynamicArray::IntegerDynamicArray()
   {
      dynamicArray = new int [maxSize];
   }
   IntegerDynamicArray::~IntegerDynamicArray()
   {
      delete [] dynamicArray;
   }

int IntegerDynamicArray::add(int x)
   {
     cout<<x<<endl;
      if(dynamicArray[currentSize-1]!=0)
      {
         int * newArray;
         newArray= new int[currentSize*2];
         for(int i =0;i<currentSize;i++)
         {
            newArray[i]=dynamicArray[i];
            newArray[currentSize]=x;

         }
         currentSize=currentSize*2;
         dynamicArray = newArray;


      }
      else
      {
         int * newArray;
         newArray= new int[currentSize];
         for(int i =0;i<currentSize;i++)
         {
            newArray[i]=dynamicArray[i];
            newArray[currentSize-1]=x;

         }

          dynamicArray = newArray;



      }
      return *dynamicArray;
   }




int main() {
    IntegerDynamicArray intDynArray;
    while (1) {
        char input;
        cout << "Enter A for add or anything else to quit: ";
        cin >> input;
        if (input == 'A') {
            cout << "Enter number to add: ";
            int x;
            cin >> x;
            cout << intDynArray.add(x) << endl;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a *lot easier* by using `std::vector`.  The `std::vector` manages memory allocation for you, including expanding as necessary.

Comment: This is for a class so I am required to do it this way.

Comment: I am required to use a dynamic array

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will help you execute your program one statement at a time, *watching* values in variables.  Edit your post with the results of the debugging session.

Comment: What value is `int IntegerDynamicArray::add(int x)` supposed to return?  You have it returning the first element in the array (always).  If the function always returns the same value, you may want to make it a `void` function and not return any values.  I don't understand why the method *needs* to return a value.

Comment: See `std::copy` for copying values from old array to new array.

Comment: Please search the internet for "c++ memory leak".  When you resize the array, where do you delete the old array?

Comment: @RyanHostetter Your design is flawed.  A dynamic array should have two values, one denoting the *capacity*, i.e. the maximum number of entries before reallocation takes place, and a *size* value, denoting the actual number of entries that are valid.  Your design is not clear -- if you have 4 items, and try to add a fifth item, you resize the array to 8 and place it at entry 8 instead of entry 5.  Does that sound right to you?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. Because you didn't asked a dedicated question these are the main ones:

- Your class lacks a variable containing the index of the last written (or next free) index of the array. Instead you (mis)use `currentSize` as such index variable.
- On each call of add() you allocate a new array although it might not be full already.
- As already mentioned in the comments you do not `delete []` your old arrays after copying into the new one.
- You use 0 as indicator that a slot in your array is empty, but you do not prevent adding 0 as regular element and you do not initialize your array to zero.

Answer (score 0):

As  Thomas Matthews pointed out:

You are leaking memory while calling add(int x). For each use of new, there should be a call for delete

Consider the following:

```
 int n=10;
 int* x= new int[n];
 //assign some values

 int* temp=new int[n*2]; //create new array

 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  temp[i]=x[i]; //assign values from x

 delete[] x; //free memory

 x=temp; //assign to x address of new array
```

Manual memory managment can be risky, so consider using std::vector in future